# Adding removing rows from table - flickering

Tags: datatables

I have a table with rows initialised with ng-repeat:

```
    <table class="dataTable row-border hover" datatable="ng" dt-options="vm.dtOptions">
   ...
    <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
```

My options are:

```
//Reference at https://datatables.net/reference/option/
vm.dtOptions = {
    paging    : false,
    searching : false,
    info      : false,
    autoWidth : false,
    ordering  : false,
    responsive: true
  };
```

**Problem**

When I modify the `vm.items`,  with `vm.items.push( ... )` or `vm.items.splice` the whole table flickers - disappears and draws itself with the new collection of items.

How can I prevent this?

Ideally I would like to keep modifying the `vm.items` collection rather than manipulate the tables rows (unless they really are the same).

Answer (score 1):

When we inserts or deletes rows from datatable it need to reinit to show changes.it removes all styles used for datatable and re-renders to table.so need to keep these style by our self. 
Following css class can make it more smooth.

```
<table class="avoid-table-flicker dataTable row-border hover" datatable="ng" dt-options="vm.dtOptions">

.avoid-table-flicker{
    border-top: none !important;
    width:100% !important;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    background: #fff !important;
    clear: both;
    border-spacing: 0;
    thead{
        th{
            text-align:left;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 16px 8px;
        }
    }
    tbody{
        td:first-child {
            padding-left: 24px;
        }
        td{
            padding: 12px 8px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more trying and researching I don't believe you can avoid the flickering when using `datatable="ng"`.

Even the official example @ https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWayDataChange suffers from this problem.